# Display Random Posts from Category in Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display a random post from a custom post type where the posts have a category of "Images".

This is my code so far, I don't understand why it's not working?

```html
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_type' => 'testimonial', 'posts_per_page' => '1', 'category_name' => 'images' ) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
?>
<div class="feature boxed testimonials">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have added page number (`posts_per_page`) in string. Give the number in `integer` as below may help.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_type' => 'testimonial', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'category_name' => 'images' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work, nothing gets outputted onto the page.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work? Trying to accomplish similarly.